# Refund payment to a credit card in Paypal. Possible ?

Tags: php, paypal

IS it possible to refund the payment to a credit card ?I have integrated the refund using paypal chain payment but it refund to the paypal account and that was working fine.I need to implement the reverse transaction to credit card.

Can anyone attach code here.

Answer (score 0):

When you refund a payment made through PayPal it will go back to the original payment method if it was a creditcard, or credit product (BML, SmartConnect.) Otherwise it will go back to their PayPal balance.

If you want to refund directly to a creditcard even if they didn't pay using a credit card you need to look into **[Non Reference Credits](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoNonReferencedCredit_API_Operation_NVP/)** which requires a Payments Pro account.